# I can't get any data back from my Scala Mongo query

Tags: mongodb, scala

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a mongo-db database. I've set up a user account and I can retrieve some data using the command line tool:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\mongo.exe" database.foocorp.com:27017/mydatabase -u salimfadhley -p secretpassowrd
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://database.foocorp.com:27017/mydatabase
MongoDB server version: 3.4.4
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
> db.mycollection.find()
... got loads of data back ...
```

I was able to query the same data-set from Python as follows:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

def main():
    client = MongoClient(
        'database.foocorp.com',
        username='salimfadhley',
        password='secretpassword',
        authsource='dashboard',
        authMechanism='SCRAM-SHA-1'
    )
    db = client.dashboard
    collection = db["mycollection"]
    print(collection.find_one())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It worked perfectly as expected, first time.

But now I want to do the exact same thing from Scala:

```
import org.mongodb.scala.{Document, MongoClient, MongoCollection}


object ConnectionDemo extends App {

  val dbHost = "database.foocorp.com"
  val dbPort = 27017
  val dbUserName = "salimfadhley"
  val dbPassword = "secretpassword"
  val dbName = "mydatabase"
  val collectionName = "mycollection"
  val mongoClient = MongoClient(s"mongodb://$dbUserName:$dbPassword@$dbHost:$dbPort/?authsource=$dbName")

  val mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName)        
  val result = mongoDatabase.getCollection(collectionName).find()

  result.subscribe(
    (d:Document) => println(d.toJson()),
    (e:Throwable) => println(s"An error occurred, ${e.getMessage}"),
    () => println("Done")

  )
```

My expectation was that this code should print out an item for each thing in the collection. When I queried the collection using the exact same credentials from Robo3T and the mongo shell I got loads of results back, so I had expected to see the same thing here.

Actually this code seems to do nothing at all: It never prints any results, error or even "Done".

Also, if I intentionally give the wrong password or hostname it still does absolutely nothing. If the connection parameters are completely wrong I would expect to see some kind of error message.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you identified, the problem is that you're not waiting for the response from the database. I see in your answer that you use Await - and while that is a valid thing to do, you should really avoid using Await if you want your code to be asynchronous. While your app is awaiting a response, it can't really do anything else.

A common way around this is with [Scala Futures](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html). The benefit of a Future is that  at its core, you're assuming that there will be a response at some point, and can carry on calculating other stuff while the Future is waiting to complete. If you want to use the value of a Future, you can map inside it. This assumes that once the future is done, you will do something with the result. A generic example using a Future:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

// assuming you have a method called callDatabase in another class called connector
val thingToWaitFor: Future[String] = ???
thingToWaitFor.map {
  thing => // do something with this thing (thing is now of type String)
}
```

If you have multiple Futures you need to wait for, you will need to use Scala's flatMap function on all outer Futures and only map on the most inner one:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

val thingToWaitFor1: Future[String] = ???
val thingToWaitFor2: Future[String] = ???
val thingToWaitFor3: Future[String] = ???

thingToWaitFor1.flatMap {
  thing1 =>
    thingToWaitFor2.flatMap {
      thing2 =>
        thingToWaitFor3.map {
          thing3 => // etc
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you can do something with these mapped values (`thing1`, `thing2` and `thing3`) at any point once they've been defined, not just at the highest or lowest level.

Using Futures is much more preferred to just Awaiting a result, especially with asynchronous applications. If you're not asynchronous then I suppose Await is fine though. Just thought I'd give another option!

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, the answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41525172/mongodb-scala-driver-unable-to-retrieve-a-document). All I have to do is wait for the result to deliver, and the easiest way to do that is with Scala's "Await" function.